# document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop javascript

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

i have this code and i want to make the scroll on a div instead of the body

```
var scrollPosition = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

i tried this :

```
var divToScroll = $(".divToScroll"),
    scrollPosition = divToScroll.scrollTop || document.divToScroll.scrollTop;
```

but it is not working

```
<section class=divToScroll>
     <article>
     </article>
</section>
```

the style:

```
.divToScroll{
  position:relative;
  width:640px;
  height:320px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.divToScroll article{
   width:100%;
   height:2000px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because `divToScroll` is a jQuery object, not a native DOM node like `document.body`, and as such has no scrollTop property, but jQuery has a [scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method

```
var divToScroll = $(".divToScroll"),
    scrollPosition = divToScroll.scrollTop();
```

of course, this only works if the scrollbar is attached to that element.

Without jQuery it would be:

```
var divToScroll = document.getElementsByClassName('divToScroll')[0],
    scrollPosition = divToScroll.scrollTop;
```

Comment: and what about document.documentElement.scrollTop; for firefox  this only works on chrome

Comment: @kougiland - Chrome and Firefox attaches the scrollbar to different elements in the global scope, or in other words when the scrollbar is on the window level, where one uses the `html` tag (documentElement) and the other uses the `body` tag. When dealing with a regular element like a `DIV`, there is no difference as the scrollbar is attached to that element.